# ANDing javascript objects together

Tags: javascript

I ran across this chunk of code (modified) in our application, and am confused to how it works:

```
    function someObject()
    {
        this.someProperty = {};
        this.foo = 
        {
            bar:
            {
                baz: function() { return "Huh?" }
            }
        };

        this.getValue = function()
        {
            return (this.someProperty && this.foo.bar && this.foo.bar.baz && this.foo.bar.baz()) || null;
        }
    }

    function test()
    {
        var o = new someObject();
        var val = o.getValue();
        alert(val);
    }
```

when you call the test() function, the text "Huh?" is alerted. I'm not sure how the result of getValue is returning that, I would've thought doing A && B && C && D would have returned true, rather than the value of D.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That happens because the [Boolean Operators](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.11) in JavaScript can return an operand, and not necessarily a `Boolean` result, e.g.:

The Logical AND operator (`&&`), will return the value of the second operand if the first is *truthy*:

```
true && "foo"; // "foo"
```

And it will return the value of the first operand if it is by itself *falsy*:

```
NaN && "anything"; // NaN
0 && "anything";   // 0
```

That's why in your example `"Huh?"` is returned, because all the preceding expressions are *truthy*:

```
alert("A" && "B" && "C" && "Huh?"); // "Huh?"
alert(true && true && true && "Huh?"); // "Huh?"
```

---

The Logical OR operator (`||`) has a similar behavior, it will return the value of the second operand, if the first one is *falsy*:

```
false || "bar"; // "bar"
```

And it will return the value of the first operand if it is by itself non-falsy:

```
"foo" || "anything"; // "foo"
```

This behavior is often used to set *default values*, for example:

```
function test (arg1) {
  arg1 = arg1 || "default value";
}
```

**Note:** Falsy values are those that coerce to `false` when used in a boolean context, and they are: `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `0`, zero-length string, and of course `false`. Anything else will coerce to `true`.

Comment: this may fix his problem: !!(this.someProperty && this.foo.bar && this.foo.bar.baz && this.foo.bar.baz())    note the "!!"

Comment: On a related note, the existence of this question here is evidence that using these boolean syntactic shortcuts for logic should be considered bad form...  "Say what you mean", said the March Hare.

Comment: Excellent summary of javascripts often misunderstood operators!

Comment: Is this Javascronic? (Javascript for Python nerds?)

Answer (score 2):

&& and || don't neccesarily produce a boolean value.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#logical_operators

Comment: I was just about to add that as a comment. :) Thanks!