# Why the result of bool(true) && string is string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

test code is:

```
console.log(true && "abc");//abc
```

who can tell me why the result is `abc`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2587182

Comment: **Pro tip:** These are arguably equivalent: `someBoolVar ? DoTrue() : DoFalse()` is the same as `someBoolVar && DoTrue() || DoFalse()` but the knowing about the second one, makes it easy to write other pseudo operators in Javascript as well: ie. **coalesce**: `someVar || defaultValue`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [MDN (Logical Operators) - Logical And (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

> Returns expr1 if it can be converted to false; otherwise, returns
>   expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, && returns true if both
>   operands are true; otherwise, returns false.

`true` obviously cannot be evaluated to false, so the second value is returned which is "abc".

Answer (score 13):

The `&&` operator in JavaScript is somewhat different than in C or Java or etc.  It always returns the last evaluated subexpression value (whether the overall expression is true — "truthy" — or false — "falsy") and doesn't force a boolean result. When it fails (when one of the values is "falsy"), then similarly the result is the raw value, and not the value's boolean interpretation.

So it's like this: given `A && B`, the interpreter does the following:

1. Evaluate expression A, giving A<sub>V</sub> — the value of A
2. Let A<sub>B</sub> be the result of casting A<sub>V</sub> to boolean
3. If A<sub>B</sub> is `false`, then the value of the `&&` expression is A<sub>V</sub>
4. Evaluate expression B, giving B<sub>V</sub>
5. Return B<sub>V</sub> as the value of the `&&` expression.

Thus in an `if` statement, the `&&` expression has the same *effect* as the boolean-casting operators in C or Java, because the `if` statement itself performs a truthy/falsy test on the overall result of the expression. When used by itself however, it's more like, "give me the value of the second expression if it the first is truthy, otherwise give me the value of the first expression".

Comment: It doesn't always return the last value. `(0 && true)` returns `0` (the first value).

Comment: @Quentin that's why I qualified the statement with "when it's true, or truthy"; by "it" I meant the whole expression. I will re-word it however.

Comment: @Quentin: It returns the last value while evaluating logical operator operands. The last one that didn't break the evaluation is always stored and returned when exiting evaluation. So it so *somhow* returning the last *truthy* value.

Comment: I swear wording that last added sentence properly took about 5 tries :-)

Answer (score 2):

`&&` returns the left hand side if the left hand side evaluates as `false`, otherwise it returns the right hand size.

`true` is not `false`, so it returns the right hand side, which is your string.

```
> 0 && true // LHS is false, return LHS
0
> 1 && true // LHS is true, return RHS
true
> false && 0 // LHS is false, return LHS
false
> true && false // LHS is true, return RHS
false
```

Answer (score 2):

You can somewhat "fix" that by wrapping the expression into `!!()`:

```
!!(true && 'abc');
```

Comment: This may be confusing, because by doing the double negation you're still not returning the first operand but rather converting `abc` to boolean when doing the first negation (which converts this string to `true` since it's not empty and negates that) and then you negate it again to get the correct value out. I think you should explain the reasoning behind it that it's still `abc` getting returned, just in it's converted boolean value.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: yea, maybe "fix" should be replaced with "accomplish".

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: actually, `!!()` will return `true` if all conditions combined with `&&` are `true`. Otherwise its always `false` plus you don't have to deal with any values like OP does.

Comment: That's true, but the origin of *that* `true` value is still **not the result of the whole expression**, but the result of converting the last truthy value (`abc`) to boolean.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: yes, but I never said any different. Anyway in this instance, it makes no difference, but I get your point.

Comment: I know you didn't. I just said it may be confusing to the OP that in that case they get the result of the evaluated expression. Which is arguably also true, but the origin of it is... Well you know what I mean. If you'd say that I would likely downvote you since you'd be writing invalid statements. :) But I know you know better than that.